Button Widget will not place on Background Image
The following script has an image for a background. When I add the button widget the button does not sit on the background image, rather it sits on top of the background image and pushes the background image down. How can I have the button sit on top of the image?
#!/usr/bin/python3.9

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MainFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=3)
        self.columnconfigure(2, weight=3)

        self.button=tk.Button(text="test", height=1, width=2)
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = tk.NW)

        self.img=tk.PhotoImage(file="bg_image.png")

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(width=1860, height=1020)
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tk.NW, image=self.img)

        self.canvas.grid()

        self.img_dot = tk.PhotoImage(file="led_rd.png")
        self.canvas.create_image(200,400,image=self.img_dot)


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 

        # configure the root window
        self.geometry("850x500")
        self.option_add('*Font', 'Helvertica 9') 

#----------------------------------------------#


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    
    MainFrame(app)
    app.mainloop()


Use self.canvas.create_window() to put the button into the canvas.

You put the Button in row 0, column 0 (explicitly), and then put the Canvas in row 1, column 0 (this is the default behavior when you don't give explicit values), so of course the Button is entirely above the Canvas.
